# Openid Connect Single Signout with entitlement Mediator in Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2is as my OpenID Provider to front a web application. I am then making service calls from my application through wso2 enterprise integrator using the OAuth Mediator and the Entitlement Mediator (using wso2is as my PDP).

This all works very well. 
The problem comes when I go to log out the user.

I send the user to /oidc/logout on my wso2is server and redirect them back to logout url for my application. This also works well and logs the user out of the frontend application.

The problem comes if I then try and access a service using the logged out user's access token. It will happily allow me to access the service until the access token expires.

Ideally what I would like is that wso2ie will reject access to the service (either at the oauth mediator or the entitlement mediator stage) once a user has logged out.

I have looked at frontend logout, backend logout, and openid session management and I am not sure what is the best fit for what I am trying to do.

I have also looked at the oidc/revoke endpoint which feels like it does exactly what I need it to do but I have not been able to get it to work properly. No matter how I make the request it always complains that that client id is not in the request (even if I explicitly set it in the data being posted)

Below is my service definition in wso2ei

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--Here is the service definition-->
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ManagerPage"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="https">
    <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="scope" scope="default" type="STRING" value="openid"/>
         <oauthService password="admin"
                       remoteServiceUrl="https://a8auth-dev.ls.cbn:8443/services/"
                       username="admin"/>
         <entitlementService callbackClass="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.callback.OAUTHEntitlementCallbackHandler"
                             client="basicAuth"
                             remoteServicePassword="PASSWORD"
                             remoteServiceUrl="https://a8auth-dev.ls.cbn:8443/services"
                             remoteServiceUserName="USER">
            <onReject>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="https://a8services-dev.ls.cbn:8443/noperm/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </onReject>
            <onAccept>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="https://a8services-dev.ls.cbn:8445/manager/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </onAccept>
            <obligations/>
            <advice/>
         </entitlementService>
      </inSequence>
    </target>
    <description/>
    </proxy>
```

Do I need to create a mediator component that will check the OpenID session management? Maybe this already exists?

Do I need to extend the OAuth Mediator to better check sessions status?

Any example, links, or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OIDC spec only specifies how to deal with the authenticated session of the user (although access token is a part of the response). So in the OIDC logout, we simply deal with terminating the authenticated session of the user.

Revoking the token obtained along with OIDC login goes beyond the spec. Even in our current implementation, this is not something straightforward since we do not maintain a correlation between the id_token and the issued access token.

However, we have an extension point introduced with [1] that can be used for a similar requirement during OIDC logout flow. Something to note is that even with this extension the correlation between id_token and access token needs to be handled by the extension developer.

### [1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3227

Please follow below link as well for better explanation

http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Validity-of-access-token-after-OIDC-SLO-td158896.html#a158919

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the wrong id for the token I was trying to revoke. Once I started using the jti attribute from the jwt everything worked as expected.